# Em-dashes and interrupting one's own dialogue within the same quote

Tags: dialogue, punctuation

I am looking for an example of a specific dialogue interruption case. I've been putting a following space my entire life, an editor just told me it doesn't belong, neither of us can cite a guide example, and both of us are sure we were taught it as an official standard.

If using an em-dash or ellipsis to take the same position as a period (rather than commas or parentheses) when not immediately followed by a quote mark, should it have a space?

Examples:

- "I didn't mean— Never mind. Forget it."
- (In narration) It looked like— No. it couldn't be.
- "I didn't mean to say... I guess it doesn't matter what I meant." (I
  know guides vary between a 4th period here or stopping at 3. I
  include this in case the style choice is linked.)

Cases where I already understand there is no space:

- "I didn't mean—" She shook her head. "Never mind."
- "I didn't mean"—she stopped herself—"Never mind."

(I looked at prior rulings before deciding whether to try here or English first; let me know if I should jump over anyway.)

Comment: There is no such thing as an "official standard" when it comes to style. Only which style guide you adhere to, or which style you personally use. If you treat what comes *after* the dash as a complete sentence, then I would *personally* use a space (but others might not). If what comes before and after the dash are treated as the *same* sentence, then I would not use a space. (Again, that's just what I would personally do.)

Comment: Thank you! Please substitute "style guide" for official standard" in my explanation as often as necessary. I'll be more careful next time.